How to send messages to specific user from service layer using spring boot web socket
I was trying to send messages to a specific user from the Spring Boot application service layer. My application is a microservice application.  My requirement is,
when one of microservice send a request to a web socket service sends the received data to a specific user using a web socket.
I was using ChannelInterceptor to catch user-name and userId (That is a custom parameter).
I was struggling to get the data from ChannelInterceptor to my service layer.
Following is my implementation.
public class User implements Principal {

    private final String name;
    @Getter
    private final Long userId;

    public User(String name, Long userId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}


@Component
public class UserInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        StompCommand command = accessor.getCommand();
        // ...
        if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
            Object raw = message
                    .getHeaders()
                    .get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.USER_HEADER);

            String userName = "";
            Long userId = null;
            if (raw instanceof UserPrincipal) {
                Object name = ((UserPrincipal) raw).getName();
                userName = name != null ? name.toString() : "";

            }

            Object rawHeader = message
                    .getHeaders()
                    .get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS);

            if (rawHeader instanceof Map) {
                Object name = ((Map) rawHeader).get("userId");
                if (name instanceof ArrayList) {
                    userId = Long.valueOf(((ArrayList<?>) name).get(0).toString());

                }
            }

            User user = new User(userName, userId);

            accessor.setUser(user);
        }

        return message;
    }


}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-workflow").setHandshakeHandler(new UserHandshakeHandler());
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-workflow").setHandshakeHandler(new UserHandshakeHandler()).withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new UserInterceptor());
    }

}


@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WorkFlowActivityServiceImpl implements WorkFlowActivityService { 

private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

public String sendWebSocket (WebSocketRequestDTO dto) {

simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/flow", dto);

}
}


Currently, I am sending the data to all the users.
now I need to get the username and userId to the service layer.
How to get this User data to my service layer ?

How do you define what message needs to be sent to a user just based on subscription. If your application decides to whom the message has to be sent, then you already have the user name in your business layer, using which you can construct a message route like /user//notification. And from client side you can simply use the already available user id to  construct the destination to subscribe. If you are looking for something else, please provide exact scenario which you are trying to solve

@i_m_js WebSocketRequestDTO has the user-id. is it possible to construct the destination to subscribe from the client side with the available user-id? Could you please give me an example?
